# trying to get min and max with corresponding names

Tags: mysql

trying to write in mysql that will show the Appointment_duration, mechanic_Firstname, mechanic_lastname, customer_firstname and customer_lastname for the appointments with the max & min time but my code gives me wrong results.. I only want the max & min duration time and corresponding names only. so 2 rows

```
SELECT 
Min(Appointment.Appointment_duration) AS MINOfAppointment_duration, 
Max(Appointment.Appointment_duration) AS MAXOfAppointment_duration,
mechanic_Firstname, mechanic_lastname, customer_firstname, customer_lastname
FROM Appointment, mechanic, Customer
WHERE (mechanic.mechanic_ID=Appointment.mechanic_ID) AND (customer.customer_ID=Appointment.customer_ID);
```

records from appointment table

```
Appointment_ID  Appointment_DATE    Appointment_Duration    Mechanic_ID Customer_ID
12               08/01/2007     0:35:00                      1            5684
13               01/01/2009     2:15:36                      6            2534
14               06/12/2010     0:05:29                      7            7423
```

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: included appointment table,

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, there is no relation between the two tables `customer` and `mechanic`, you have to get the max and min duration for each table separately and use `UNION ALL` to combine the two result set into one. Something like:

```
SELECT 
  m.mechanic_Firstname AS FirstName, 
  m.mechanic_lastname AS LastName,
  IFNULL(Min(a.Appointment_duration), 0) AS MINOfAppointment_duration, 
  IFNULL(Max(a.Appointment_duration), 0) AS MAXOfAppointment_duration
FROM mechanic AS m
LEFT JOIN Appointment AS a ON a.mechanic_ID = m.mechanic_ID
GROUP BY m.mechanic_Firstname,
         m.mechanic_lastname
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  c.customer_firstname,
  c.customer_lastname,
  IFNULL(Min(a.Appointment_duration), 0), 
  IFNULL(Max(a.Appointment_duration), 0)
FROM customer AS c
LEFT JOIN Appointment AS a ON a.mechanic_ID = c.customer_ID
GROUP BY c.customer_firstname,
         c.customer_lastname;
```

This will give you only four columns:

```
FirstName  |  LastName  |  MINOfAppointment_duration  |  MAXOfAppointment_duration
```

Where all the mechanics' names and customers' names are all listed in the two columns `firstname` and `lastname`, you can add a flag to mark the mechanics from customers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Union all` function to find out max and min values.

```
    SELECT 
    Min(Appointment.Appointment_duration) AS Appointment_duration, 'Min' as status,
    mechanic_Firstname, mechanic_lastname, customer_firstname, customer_lastname
    FROM Appointment, mechanic, Customer
    WHERE (mechanic.mechanic_ID=Appointment.mechanic_ID) 
    AND (customer.customer_ID=Appointment.customer_ID);
Union all
    SELECT  
    Max(Appointment.Appointment_duration) AS  Appointment_duration,'Max' as status,
    mechanic_Firstname, mechanic_lastname, customer_firstname, customer_lastname
    FROM Appointment, mechanic, Customer
    WHERE (mechanic.mechanic_ID=Appointment.mechanic_ID)
    AND (customer.customer_ID=Appointment.customer_ID);
```